# ASP.net unable to UPDATE column in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server-2014-express

I'm creating an online application where I'm trying to update data through asp.net winforms. I have a `textbox` named `tbCompanyName` and a column in my database named `companyName`, in table `tblCompanySetup`.

I'm SELECTING previous data from column perfectly, but when I try to update data, it is not updating data, although don't showing any errors. I have worked in C# desktop application, but I'm completely newbie in ASP.NET.

I think there may be any `AUTOPOSTBACK` issues, but I don't know how to resolve. I'm posting my code that I'm using for updating the data in a SQL Server table. Help me please.

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConStr))
{
    string query = @"UPDATE tblCompanySetup SET companyName = @companyName";

    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tbCompanyName.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: I have previous value in textbox that I'm using for a new value to update. It's working fine when I put that textbox empty and type new value. But when I select previous value in textbox and then input new value and click submit, it is actually saving the previous value I guess.. Also when I press the submit button, it refreshes the form and put the previous value again

Comment: do you only have 1 row in the table  ? where do you select the row to update ?

Comment: yes i have only 1 row therefore i didn't included WHERE clause.

Comment: you must declare (@companyName ) in your query . DECLARE @companyName nvarchar  or simply use cmd.Parameters.Add("@companyName",SqlDbType.NVarChar)=tbCompanyName.Text;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have retrieving method from a database on a page load. Something like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    RetrieveMyData(); // it is a method where you retrieve a data
}
```

Change this to:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if (!IsPostBack)
        RetrieveMyData(); // it is a method where you retrieve a data
}
```

Your project works like:

1) Page_Load -> RetrieveMyData()

2) Your textbox has some value from a database

3) You changing that value to a new value

4) You click on a UPDATE button

5) As you don't consider PostBack, it calls again RetrieveMyData and your textbox has the old value

6) Your Update method executes, but no changes occurs

If you will use PostBack as I showed:

1) Page_Load -> RetrieveMyData

2) Your textbox has some value from a database

3) You change that value

4) You click on a Update button

5) As you use *!IsPostBack* and button occur a postback, your RetrieveMyData method will not work here

6) Your update method will update the old value with a new one

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks @Khazratbek for the great answer. really helpful